# How do i find if an array value is in a string and remove it?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want something like this:

```
var string = "apple banana";
var array = ["apple", "banana", "orange", "grape"];
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
  if(array[i] is found in (string) {
    remove the value;
  }
}
```

something like that. so basically, it would:

- Declare a string and an array
- Iterate through the array
- If the array[i] value is present exactly in the string, it would remove it
- The iteration should continue as normal

In case it still doesnt make sense:

String is "1 3 b c"

Array contains "1", "2","3", "a", "b", "c"

The array should now only contain "2" and "a".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.filter` the array by whether the string does not `.includes` the substring being iterated over:

```js
const doFilter = (str, arr) => arr.filter(substr => !str.includes(substr));

console.log(
  doFilter("apple banana", ["apple", "banana", "orange", "grape"]),
  doFilter("1 3 b c", ["1", "2","3", "a", "b", "c"]),
);
```

Comment: I think you need `array.filter(substr => !string.includes(substr))` to remove the matching items.